# How do I manually create a .atlas file?

Tags: java, andengine

I am trying to learn Andengine, and it seems it does not support sprites in any other way other thab a Texture Atlas. I am using the Android AIDE app and importing the older Andengine .JAR because I dont have a laptop and dont plan on forking up $250-400 for one when I can get a quad core android for $100 flat. I want to make a simple .ATLAS file but dont know how. Does anyone else here know how to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by buying laptop for AndEngine?

Comment: @nikoliazekter I mean that since I don't own one and don't intend on buying one and have an Android tablet and use the Android IDE to develop I downloaded the .JAR and started developing. Ran into trouble when dealing with atlases.

Comment: Oh, i understood. This really exacerbates the problem.

Comment: @nikoliazekter AIDE is basically a version of Eclipse for Android. I actually reconfigured it to support Lua and C#(I decompiled the application and modified it before using the installed version of AIDE to recompile it). Having trouble making it build windows store appx files because it is built to make apk's but I will eventually get it. Answers should just assume it is eclipse.